# Python function that returns sum of negative numbers in list

Tags: python

My funtion needs to take a list of integers and return the sum of the negative integers in the list. How can I fix this so that the list objects are seen as integers?

```
def sumNegativeInts(listInt):
    sumNegative=0
    for x in listInt.split(','):
        if int(x) < 0:
            sumNegative+=listInt(x)
    return sumNegative
```

Comment: There are a number of potentially incorrect things wrong with your code, but we can't know for sure out of context. Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to `split` a list.

```
def sumNegativeInts(listInt):
    m = 0
    for x in listInt:
        if x < 0:
            m+=x
    return(int(m))

a = [1, 3, 4, 5, -2, -3, 4, -1]
print sumNegativeInts(a)
```

Output *(-2 + -3 + -1)*:

```
-6
```

A better way using generator expressions:

```
print sum(x for x in a if x<0)
```

Comment: FYI, your "better way" is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If your "list" isn't a string your number are stored sequentially.

```
def sumNegativeInts(listInt):
    sum_result = 0
    for x in listInt:
        if x < 0:
            sum_result += x
    return(int(sum_result))
```

Note that if your number are all int you don't need to cast sum when returning it.

Comment: Note that by using the name `sum` you're shadowing a built-in function that would be really useful in this situation...

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right. Edited with another name